# How can a compiler be cross platform(hardware)?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compilation, cross-platform

I just realized that binary compilers convert source code to the binary of the destination platform. Kind of obvious... but if a compiler works such way, then how can the same compiler be used for different systems like x86, ARM, MIPS, etc?

Shouldn't they be supposed to "know" the machine-language of the hardware platform to be able to know how to build the binary? Does a compiler(like gcc) knows the machine language of every single platform that is supported?

How is that system possible, and how can a compiler be optimized for that many platforms at the same time?

Comment: "Does a compiler(like gcc) knows the machine language of every single platform that is supported?"  A single version of GCC won't, as it will be targeted towards a specific CPU family. But support for all those platforms exist in the GCC source code tree so that you can build versions of GCC for each of those targets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they have to "know" the machine language for every single platform they support. This is a required to generate machine code. However, compilation is a multi-step process. Usually, the first steps of the compilation are common to most architectures.

**Taken from wikipedia**

> **Structure of a compiler**
>
> Compilers bridge source programs in high-level
>   languages with the underlying hardware.
>
> A compiler requires
>
> 1. determining the correctness of the syntax of programs,
> 2. generating correct and efficient object code,
> 3. run-time organization, and
> 4. formatting output according to assembler and/or linker conventions.
>
> A
>   compiler consists of three main parts: the frontend, the middle-end,
>   and the backend.
>
> **The front end**
>
> checks whether the program is correctly
>   written in terms of the programming language syntax and semantics.
>   Here legal and illegal programs are recognized. Errors are reported,
>   if any, in a useful way. Type checking is also performed by collecting
>   type information. The frontend then generates an intermediate
>   representation or IR of the source code for processing by the
>   middle-end.
>
> **The middle end**
>
> is where optimization takes place. Typical
>   transformations for optimization are removal of useless or unreachable
>   code, discovery and propagation of constant values, relocation of
>   computation to a less frequently executed place (e.g., out of a loop),
>   or specialization of computation based on the context. The middle-end
>   generates another IR for the following backend. Most optimization
>   efforts are focused on this part.
>
> **The back end**
>
> is responsible for translating the IR from the middle-end into assembly code. The target
>   instruction(s) are chosen for each IR instruction. Register allocation
>   assigns processor registers for the program variables where possible.
>   The backend utilizes the hardware by figuring out how to keep parallel
>   execution units busy, filling delay slots, and so on. Although most
>   algorithms for optimization are in NP, heuristic techniques are
>   well-developed.

More this article which describes the [structure of a compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Structure_of_a_compiler) and on this one which deals with [Cross compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

Answer (score 2):

The http://llvm.org/ project will answer all of your questions in this regard :)
In a nutshell, cross HW compilers emit "intermediate representation" of the code , which is HW agnostic and then its being customized via the *native* tool chain

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, it's called [Cross Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). Compilers usually first they generate the [object code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code) which is not understanable by the current machine but it can be migrated to the destiny machine with another compiler. Next, object code is "compiled" again and linked with external libraries of the target machines.

**TL;DR:** Yes, the compilers knows the target code, but you can compile in another hardware.

I recommend you to read attached links for information.

Answer (score 2):

Every platform has its own toolchain, toolchain includes gcc,gdb,ld,nm etc.

Let's take specific example of gcc as of now. GCC source code has many layers including architecture dependent and independent part. Architecture dependent part contains procedures to handle architecture specific things like their stack, function calls, floating point operations. We need to cross compile the gcc source code for a specific architecture like for ARM. You can see its steps here for reference:- http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-arm-cross-compiling-howto.html#toolchain.

This architecture dependent part is responsible for handling machine language operations.